# developers appengine throws 404 Not Found error with users.create_logout_url(self.request.uri)

Tags: google-app-engine, http-status-code-404, logout

It seems illogical that this statement could throw a 404 error. Any ideas?

```
users.create_logout_url(self.request.uri)



INFO     2012-06-30 16:20:47,374 dev_appserver.py:2952] "GET /('/_ah/login?continue=http%3A//localhost%3A8082/%3FID%3DtestBSchott&action=Logout',) HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

New info follows.

```
key = db.Key.from_path("PQ", ID_id)
person = PQ.get(key)
if person: #person's ID DOES exist already
    if user and user == person.user: #user is owner and may revise the existing page
        choices = ' '.join(person.choices)
        url = users.create_logout_url(self.request.uri),
        template_values = {'ID_id':person.key(),
                'p': person,
                'choices': choices,
                'url': url 
                }
        logging.info("7 url %s" % url )
        logging.info("7 template_values %s" % template_values )
        path = os.path.join(TEMPLATE_DIR, 'add_person.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))
```

I have not shown all the variable in the template_values above; just the key ones. But from the log below, you can see that the value of url has changed within the template_values to be the nasty tuple you diagnosed. The question for me is why and what can I do?

```
INFO     2012-06-30 19:10:38,479 views.py:209] 7 url /_ah/login?continue=http%3A//localhost%3A8082/%3FID%3DtestBSchott&action=Logout
INFO     2012-06-30 19:10:38,479 views.py:210] 7 template_values {'month': 9, 'year': 2012, 'years': [2012, 2013, 2014], 'day': 3, 'url': ('/_ah/login?continue=http%3A//localhost%3A8082/%3FID%3DtestBSchott&action=Logout',), 'months': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], 'ID_id': datastore_types.Key.from_path(u'PQ', u'testBSchott', _app=u'dev~youpoll'), 'days': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31], 'choices': u'Less Same More', 'p': <models.PQ object at 0x10bd6bf10>, 'nowyear': (2012,)}
INFO     2012-06-30 19:10:38,479 views.py:212] 6 path /Users/brian/googleapps/YouPoll/templates/add_person.html
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the logs. The URL being fetched is incorrect:

```
/('/_ah/login?continue=http%3A//localhost%3A8082/%3FID%3DtestBSchott&action=Logout',)
```

This is a "/" followed by a python tuple with one item, which is the correct URL. What are you doing with the result of the create_logout_url call? Try logging the result of the call directly; if it's a tuple, that's a bug in app engine, but my guess is that you're somehow putting it in to a tuple later by accident.

Comment: I added the log info message to the question. I am surprised about the error too.

Comment: I just noticed a suspicious comma in the log info after the word logout. But I cannot find such in my code.

Comment: The comma (as well as the parenthesis and quote marks) are because the URL is being wrapped in a python tuple somewhere. I've added some suggestions to my answer; you might also try posting more of the code surrounding your call to create_logout_url.

Comment: Jesse, I have added more logging info and it shows a problem, but no solution. Could you look at it please?

Comment: @zerowords The problem is that you have a comma at the end of this line: `url = users.create_logout_url(self.request.uri),`

Comment: Ironically, the logging method you used to log the url has special behaviour if you pass it a tuple, which is why it didn't show up in your first log statement but it does in the log of template_values

Comment: I noticed that problem at another location and fixed it, but not here. You are exactly right. Great work.